# Drawing triangles with opengl with GL/gl.h and GL/glx.h on x11 System

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glx

I have read and pieced multiple projects together in order to create an x11 window with open gl working, with the preinstalled GL/gl.h and GL/glx.h. The problem I get is that the triangles I want to draw to the screen does not show. What I think is that I have not setup any projecting parameters etc, or that the triangles doesn't get drawn to the space I want to draw to.

I do get a window and I am able to setup xevents that triggers after I have subscribed with eventmasks. Pressing 'esc' key will trigger an event which will in the end call `Shutdown()` and break the loop, free up x11 and gl stuff, and lastly exit the program. So the only thing that doesn't work is the drawing to screen stuff which basically is the main point of my program.

How can I resolve this?

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstring>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/keysymdef.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define WINDOW_WIDTH    800
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT   600
#define FPS 30
#define TEST_LOCAL

int shutdown = 0;

extern bool Initialize(int w, int h);
extern bool Update(float deltaTime);
extern void Render();
extern void HandleKeyboardEvents( XEvent );
extern void Resize(int w, int h);
extern void Shutdown();

typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);

#define SKIP_TICKS      (1000 / FPS)

static double GetMilliseconds() {
    static timeval s_tTimeVal;
    gettimeofday(&s_tTimeVal, NULL);
    double time = s_tTimeVal.tv_sec * 1000.0; // sec to ms
    time += s_tTimeVal.tv_usec / 1000.0; // us to ms
    return time;
}

static bool isExtensionSupported(const char *extList, const char *extension) {
    return strstr(extList, extension) != 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Display* display;
    Window window;
    Screen* screen;
    int screenId;
    XEvent ev;

    // Open the display
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (display == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Could not open display\n";
        return 1;
    }
    screen = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(display);
    screenId = DefaultScreen(display);
    
    // Check GLX version
    GLint majorGLX, minorGLX = 0;
    glXQueryVersion(display, &majorGLX, &minorGLX);
    if (majorGLX <= 1 && minorGLX < 2) {
        std::cout << "GLX 1.2 or greater is required.\n";
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        return 1;
    }

    GLint glxAttribs[] = {
        GLX_X_RENDERABLE    , True,
        GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE   , GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
        GLX_RENDER_TYPE     , GLX_RGBA_BIT,
        GLX_X_VISUAL_TYPE   , GLX_TRUE_COLOR,
        GLX_RED_SIZE        , 8,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE      , 8,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE       , 8,
        GLX_ALPHA_SIZE      , 8,
        GLX_DEPTH_SIZE      , 24,
        GLX_STENCIL_SIZE    , 8,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER    , True,
        None
    };
    
    int fbcount;
    GLXFBConfig* fbc = glXChooseFBConfig(display, screenId, glxAttribs, &fbcount);
    if (fbc == 0) {
        std::cout << "Failed to retrieve framebuffer.\n";
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        return 1;
    }

    // Pick the FB config/visual with the most samples per pixel
    int best_fbc = -1, worst_fbc = -1, best_num_samp = -1, worst_num_samp = 999;
    for (int i = 0; i < fbcount; ++i) {
        XVisualInfo *vi = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, fbc[i] );
        if ( vi != 0) {
            int samp_buf, samples;
            glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, &samp_buf );
            glXGetFBConfigAttrib( display, fbc[i], GLX_SAMPLES       , &samples  );

            if ( best_fbc < 0 || (samp_buf && samples > best_num_samp) ) {
                best_fbc = i;
                best_num_samp = samples;
            }
            if ( worst_fbc < 0 || !samp_buf || samples < worst_num_samp )
                worst_fbc = i;
            worst_num_samp = samples;
        }
        XFree( vi );
    }
    GLXFBConfig bestFbc = fbc[ best_fbc ];
    XFree( fbc ); // Make sure to free this!

    
    XVisualInfo* visual = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( display, bestFbc );
    if (visual == 0) {
        std::cout << "Could not create correct visual window.\n";
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (screenId != visual->screen) {
        std::cout << "screenId(" << screenId << ") does not match visual->screen(" << visual->screen << ").\n";
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        return 1;

    }

    // Open the window
    XSetWindowAttributes windowAttribs;
    windowAttribs.border_pixel = BlackPixel(display, screenId);
    windowAttribs.background_pixel = WhitePixel(display, screenId);
    windowAttribs.override_redirect = True;
    windowAttribs.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, RootWindow(display, screenId), visual->visual, AllocNone);
    windowAttribs.event_mask = ExposureMask;
    window = XCreateWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screenId), 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, visual->depth, InputOutput, visual->visual, CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWEventMask, &windowAttribs);

    // Redirect Close
    Atom atomWmDeleteWindow = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, window, &atomWmDeleteWindow, 1);

    // Create GLX OpenGL context
    glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = 0;
    glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc) glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB" );
    
    int context_attribs[] = {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
        GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        None
    };

    GLXContext context = 0;
    const char *glxExts = glXQueryExtensionsString( display,  screenId );
    if (!isExtensionSupported( glxExts, "GLX_ARB_create_context")) {
        std::cout << "GLX_ARB_create_context not supported\n";
        context = glXCreateNewContext( display, bestFbc, GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, True );
    }
    else {
        context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB( display, bestFbc, 0, true, context_attribs );
    }
    XSync( display, False );

    // Verifying that context is a direct context
    if (!glXIsDirect (display, context)) {
        std::cout << "Indirect GLX rendering context obtained\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Direct GLX rendering context obtained\n";
    }
    glXMakeCurrent(display, window, context);

    std::cout << "GL Renderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << "\n";
    std::cout << "GL Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << "\n";
    std::cout << "GLSL Version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << "\n";

    if (!Initialize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)) {
        glXDestroyContext(display, context);
        XFree(visual);
        XFreeColormap(display, windowAttribs.colormap);
        XDestroyWindow(display, window);
        XCloseDisplay(display);
        return 1;
    }

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glOrtho( 0, 640, 480, 0, -1, 1 );

    XSelectInput( display, window, PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | KeyPressMask );

    // Show the window
    XClearWindow(display, window);
    XMapRaised(display, window);

    double prevTime = GetMilliseconds();
    double currentTime = GetMilliseconds();
    double deltaTime = 0.0;

    timeval time;
    long sleepTime = 0;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    long nextGameTick = (time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000);

    // Enter message loop
    while (shutdown != 1) {
        if (XPending(display) > 0) {
            XNextEvent(display, &ev);
            if (ev.type == Expose) {
                XWindowAttributes attribs;
                XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &attribs);
                Resize(attribs.width, attribs.height);
            }
            if (ev.type == ClientMessage) {
                if (ev.xclient.data.l[0] == atomWmDeleteWindow) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (ev.type == DestroyNotify) { 
                break;
            }
        }

        currentTime = GetMilliseconds();
        deltaTime = double(currentTime - prevTime) * 0.001;
        prevTime = currentTime;

        if (!Update((float)deltaTime)) {
            break;
        }
        HandleKeyboardEvents( ev );
        Render();

        // Present frame
        glXSwapBuffers(display, window);

        // Limit Framerate
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        nextGameTick += SKIP_TICKS;
        sleepTime = nextGameTick - ((time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000));
        usleep((unsigned int)(sleepTime / 1000));
    }

    std::cout << "Shutting Down\n";
    Shutdown();

    // Cleanup GLX
    glXDestroyContext(display, context);

    // Cleanup X11
    XFree(visual);
    XFreeColormap(display, windowAttribs.colormap);
    XDestroyWindow(display, window);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}

#ifdef TEST_LOCAL
bool Initialize(int w, int h) {
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.6f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    return true;
}

bool Update(float deltaTime) {
    return true;
}

void HandleKeyboardEvents( XEvent ev ) {
    int x, y;

    switch ( ev.type ) {
        case ButtonPress:
            if ( ev.xbutton.button == 1 ) {
                std::cout << "Left mouse down \n";
            }
            break;
        case ButtonRelease:
            if ( ev.xbutton.button == 1 ) {
                std::cout << "Left mouse up \n";
            }
            break;
        case KeyPress:
            if ( ev.xkey.keycode == 9 ) { // ESC
                Shutdown();
            }
            break;
        case MotionNotify:
            x = ev.xmotion.x;
            y = ev.xmotion.y;
            //std::cout << "Mouse X:" << x << ", Y: " << y << "\n";
            break;  
    }
}

void Render() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3f(  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f);
        glColor3f(  1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f);
    
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void Resize(int w, int h) {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void Shutdown() {
    shutdown = 1;   
}
#endif
```

I compile with:

```
g++ -g -Wall -o _build/main main.cpp -I/opt/x11/include  -L/usr/x11/lib -lGL -lX11
```

OS:

```
Linux kali 5.9.0-kali4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.11-1kali1 (2020-12-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You set up your projection so the coordinates go from 0,0 to 640,480: `glOrtho( 0, 640, 480, 0, -1, 1 );` but then you render your triangle between -1 and 1. Your triangle is going to take up a few pixels at most, and be right in the corner of the screen.

Comment: Good point @user253751 but when changing lines in ```Render()``` to ```  glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
  glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
  glVertex3f( 640.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
  glVertex3f( 0.0f, 480.0f, 0.0f );
``` it still doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will not render the triangle, but will generate `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` on your `glBegin`/`glEnd` construct instead. The reason lies here:

> ```
> int context_attribs[] = {
>     GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
>     GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
>     GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
>     None
> };
> ```

According to the [`GLX_ARB_create_context`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/GLX_ARB_create_context.txt) GLX extension spec (emphasis mine):

> If version 3.2 or greater is requested, the context returned may implement any of the following versions:
>
> - The **requested profile** of the requested version.
> - The **requested profile** of any later version, so long as no features have been removed from that later version and profile.

with the profile being requested via the `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` attribute, which you ommitted, so the default will apply:

> The default value for `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` is
> `GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`. All OpenGL 3.2 implementations are
> required to implement the core profile, but implementation of the
> compatibility profile is optional.

The legacy features like `glBegin`/`glEnd` drawing mode, the fixed-function pipeline, the matrix stack are all **removed** from core profiles of OpenGL.

To get this code to run, you have 3 options:

1. Request a GL version <= 2.1. This will get you the most compatibility with legacy implementations. And it will basically yield the same result as if you don't use the `GLX_ARB_create_context` extension at all.
2. Explicitly request GL 3.2 with `GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` (and remove the `GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB`). This might or might not work depending on wether your implementation supports.
3. Keep the GL context as 3.2 core, and just write core-profile compatible code.

Option 3 is actually the only one which makes sense in the year 2021. However, it will require much more setup code than you currently have. You will have to write your own shaders, and set up a VAO together with a VBO for the vertex attributes and the respective data arrays.

Note that option 3 will also break the

> with the preinstalled GL/gl.h and GL/glx.h.

part of your premise. You'll want to drop at least the `gl.h` header in favor of one generated by a [GL loader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Comment: By including something else than gl.h, probably glew.h, do I need to install it to my system or can I pass it as a resource? And also, after compiling, do I still need the library if I move to another machine or does the other machine also need the lib installed? If the OS and architecture remains the same.

Comment: If you take a look at [glad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad), you will notice that it is a load _generator_, which _generates_ the actual _source code_ which you can include into your project, so it does not add any additional external dependencies. The glad2 branch is especially nice, as it allows you to create a [single header file](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad/wiki/C#header-only) for everything. There is also the [webservice](https://gen.glad.sh/) where you can generate the stuff remotely.

Comment: Also note that in your scenario with raw `glX`, according to the [glX spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glx1.4.pdf), `glXGetProcAddress` is guaranteed to also resolve all core non-extension function pointers (which isn't the case with `wglGetProcAddress` on windows), so you can directly pass that function as loader function to `gladLoadGL`, you don't need to add glad's built-in loader, and you don't need to fiddle with `libdl` at all.

Comment: Alright thank you. But by using glad, if I want to transfer my compiled code to another machine, will it still work or will it rely on the installed glad dependencies? Like if I install the dependencies on my machine, create my application, and compile the program and output an executable, will that file be executable on all x11 machines?

Comment: Yes. As I said, it does not add any extra depencencies. It only generates some source code which you could also have written yourself.